# Java convert else { if {} } to elseif {}

Tags: java, if-statement, converters

I'm looking for any existing code or library in java or a similar language to convert given the following (which is not java, but a custom language)

```
if (i < 0) {
    i = 0;
} else {
    if (i > 100) {
        i = 100;
    }
}
```

into elseif like this:

```
if (i < 0) {
    i = 0;
} else if (i > 100) {
    i = 100;
}
```

This code is not java but I want to convert it using java.

Here is what I tried to acomplish this but it's not working

```
        String elseB = "else {";
        int index = output.indexOf(elseB);
        while (index != -1) {
            output = output.substring(index + 1);
            index = output.indexOf(elseB);
            if (index != -1) {
                int ifAt = index + elseB.length() + 1;
                String elseStart = output.substring(ifAt).trim();
                if (elseStart.startsWith("if")) {
                    int closingBracket = findClosingBracket(
                        output.toCharArray(), index);
                    int openingBracket = ifAt - 1;
                    String justBlock = output.substring(openingBracket,
                        closingBracket).trim();
                    output = output.substring(0, openingBracket - 1) + justBlock + output.substring(closingBracket);
                }
            }

        }
```

a more complicated example would be converting this:

```
if (i == 1) {

} else {
    if (i == 2) {

    } else {
        if (i == 3) {

        } else {
            if (i == 4) {

            } else {
                if (i == 5) {

                } else {
                    if (i == 6) {

                    } else {
                        if (i == 7) {

                        } else {
                            if (i == 8) {

                            } else {
                                if (i == 9) {

                                } else {
                                    if (i == 10) {

                                    } else {
                                        if (i == 22) {

                                        } else {
                                            if (i == 11) {

                                            } else {
                                                if (i == 12) {

                                                } else {
                                                    if (i == 25) {

                                                    } else {
                                                        if (i == 13) {

                                                        } else {
                                                            if (i == 14) {

                                                            } else {
                                                                if (i == 15) {

                                                                } else {
                                                                    if (i == 24) {

                                                                    } else {
                                                                        if (i == 16) {

                                                                        } else {
                                                                            if (i == 17) {

                                                                            } else {
                                                                                if (i == 18) {

                                                                                } else {
                                                                                    if (i == 21) {

                                                                                    } else {
                                                                                        if (i == 19) {

                                                                                        } else {
                                                                                            if (i == 20) {

                                                                                            } else {
                                                                                                if (i == 23) {

                                                                                                } else {

                                                                                                }
                                                                                            }
                                                                                        }
                                                                                    }
                                                                                }
                                                                            }
                                                                        }
                                                                    }
                                                                }
                                                            }
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

into this

```
if (i == 1) {

} else if (i == 2) {

} else if (i == 3) {

} else if (i == 4) {

} else if (i == 5) {

} else if (i == 6) {

} else if (i == 7) {

} else if (i == 8) {

} else if (i == 9) {

} else if (i == 10) {

} else if (i == 22) {

} else if (i == 11) {

} else if (i == 12) {

} else if (i == 25) {

} else if (i == 13) {

} else if (i == 14) {

} else if (i == 15) {

} else if (i == 24) {

} else if (i == 16) {

} else if (i == 17) {

} else if (i == 18) {

} else if (i == 21) {

} else if (i == 19) {

} else if (i == 20) {

} else if (i == 23) {

} else {

}
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean? Some sort of IDE plugin?

Comment: @BorisTheSpider Either way, it's an off-topic request for a tool or library, isn't it?

Comment: @yshavit yes, of course. But I'd like to know what the OP is asking exactly before I vote to close. I'm more inclined to close as unclear at the juncture...

Comment: @BorisTheSpider I have code decompiled from a custom programming language. I dont need any IDE plugin, just a method which can convert it. I tried myself but it didnt work.

Comment: To be honest, instead of changing that to `else if`, I would try avoid the whole `if/else` in the first place, since a code smells stays a code smells even if you "polish" it a bit.

Comment: @Tom The code is not written by me. I have thousands of scripts using code like this and need to make it nicer

Comment: Well, it is not so important who had written that, but since you're currently working on it, try to get time to do a proper refactoring. But yes, it would need much time, but it's worth it.

Comment: If the blocks of code you need to parse are in valid Java syntax (as is the case with the examples), you might be able to use a Java source parser such as [JavaParser](http://javaparser.github.io/javaparser/) for most of the work.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you want to change the code, not the compiled bytecode. For that you would look into text replacing. Depending on your editor you can replace all the instances of this text with the elif statement. If your editor can *not* do it, look into regular expressions. With those you can change the lines in no time.

Answer (score -2):

If trying to test a single value vs various conditions,could try to use switch statemenet instead various if statements.

ie.

```
switch(i){
    case(i <= 0):
        i=0;
    case(i >= 100):
        i=100;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work in Java. The cases must be constants, and are checked only for equality.

Comment: @yshavit As the author says, the code to process "is not Java". So we don't know whether it works in his language.

Comment: @qqilihq That edit (in the question) wasn't there at the time I made my comment. With that edit, I would amend my comment to something like, "without knowing what the target language is, there's no reason to assume this syntax would be valid in it." Either way, this answer doesn't seem to cut it. (But for the record, I'm not one of the downvoters.)